# finally statement not working in try/catch java?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, try-catch-finally

I am trying to access a database in netbeans, and this is the first time I have done this. I have a problem when I get to the `finally` statement. The `Connection` and the `PrintWriter` don't seem to register and I'm not sure what I have done wrong. The issue comes with using the variable `con` in the `try/catch` and then the variable `out` after it.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


@WebServlet(name = "DBServlet1", urlPatterns = {"/db1"})
public class DBServlet1 extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    //Connection con = null;
    //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        Connection con = null;

        // Load the Driver class file
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");

        // Make a connection to the ODBC datasource Movie Catalog
        // In this example we are opening a connection to the
        // database with every request.
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/movies","user1", "password");

        if ( con != null ) {
            out.println("<html>\n<body>\n<table border=\"1\" width=\"100%\">");
            // Create the statement
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER1.TMovie");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            out.println("<tr>");

            for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++) {
                out.println("<td><h3>" +rsmd.getColumnName(i) + "</td>");
            }
            out.println("</tr>");

            while ( rs.next() ) {
                out.println("<tr>");
                // get the id, which is an int
                out.println("<td>" + rs.getInt("id") + "</td>");
                // get the name, which is a String
                out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("title") + "</td>");
                // get the rating, which is a String
                out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("rating") + "</td>");
                // get the price, which is a Float
                out.println("<td>" + rs.getFloat("price") + "</td>");
                // get the Quantity, which is a Integer
                out.println("<td>" + rs.getInt("quantity") + "</td>");
                // get the Category, which is a Integer
                out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("category") + "</td>");
                out.println("</tr>");
            }// end while
            // Close the ResultSet
            rs.close();
            out.println("</table>");
        }// end if
        else {
            out.println("Data Not Found");
        }
   }catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }// end try-catch
    finally {
        try{
            if ( con != null ) {
                // Close the connection no matter what
                con.close();
            }// end if
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.err.println(sqle.getMessage());
        }// end try-catch
    }// end finally
    out.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Connection and the PrintWriter don't seem to register and I'm not sure what I have done wrong.

They're both declared *within* the `try` block. So just like any other block-scoped variable, they aren't accessible outside that block. If you need to access them in the `catch` or `finally`, you need to declare them outside the `try`.

---

Side note: The code would be simpler if you used a try-with-resources statement for all the auto-closeables (not just the `PrintWriter`), e.g. with the connection and statement(s) as well; and if you use it correctly (you don't close the things you open in the try-with-resources, it does); [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Here's an example, note the `***` comments:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    // Load the Driver class file
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // *** Ideally, do something more useful with the exception or *don't* catch it
       System.err.println(e.getMessage());
       return;
    }

    try (
        // *** Note all auto-closeables are created here
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        // Make a connection to the ODBC datasource Movie Catalog
        // In this example we are opening a connection to the
        // database with every request.
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/movies","user1", "password");
        // Create the statement
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER1.TMovie");
        ) {

        out.println("<html>\n<body>\n<table border=\"1\" width=\"100%\">");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        out.println("<tr>");

        for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++) {
            out.println("<td><h3>" +rsmd.getColumnName(i) + "</td>");
        }
        out.println("</tr>");

        while ( rs.next() ) {
            out.println("<tr>");
            // get the id, which is an int
            out.println("<td>" + rs.getInt("id") + "</td>");
            // get the name, which is a String
            out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("title") + "</td>");
            // get the rating, which is a String
            out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("rating") + "</td>");
            // get the price, which is a Float
            out.println("<td>" + rs.getFloat("price") + "</td>");
            // get the Quantity, which is a Integer
            out.println("<td>" + rs.getInt("quantity") + "</td>");
            // get the Category, which is a Integer
            out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("category") + "</td>");
            out.println("</tr>");
        }// end while
        // *** Don't close auto-closeables like the result set
        out.println("</table>");
        /* *** This else was connected to an if (con != null), so the message doesn't really make sense
        else {
            out.println("Data Not Found");
        }
        */
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // *** Ideally, do something more useful here or don't catch the exception
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    // *** No `finally` at all
}
```

I **haven't** done a full code audit or anything, I've just looked at the use of resources and pointed out changes related to handling them correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I don't have any errors in the code now and have a little better understanding, but this still isn't displaying the db values

Comment: I had the wrong address for the db, all fixed! Thank you for a detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

The scope of the variable con and out is not correct. You need to declare them before try/catch/finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variables before try-with-resource block:-

```
Connection con = null;          
PrintWriter out =null,
```

and then write  try-with-resource block like this:-

```
try ( out = response.getWriter()) {  
//here is your code
```